# Estructura de programa de inventario para una panadería en Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, macros

[image: en la imagen se puede observar que esta el listado de ingredientes de un producto, esa información necesito registrarla en visual basic de excel]
Estamos desarrollando un programa en excel que nos determine el costo unitario de un producto para nuestro ejemplo es el pan
Por medio de un kardex necesito ingresar las órdenes de compra(estas ordenes son el ingreso a inventario de los productos como la harina, pan leche, huevos etc) de la materia prima y por una orden de producción (la orden de producción se realiza para indicar que se esta elaborando el producto churro) hacer el registro del producto a elaborar, cada producto tiene una lista de ingredientes se determinan la cantidad exacta que se consume un solo producto para comenzar a registrar la cantidad que se requiere elaborar, es decir, que si voy a realizar el producto churro necesito estructurar como programar para que al seleccionar el producto churro este me descargue de lo que tengo en existencias la materia prima que yo estoy utilizando para producirlo y así cuando se este acabando los insumos pueda comenzar a comprar más

De ahí me debe descargar de los ingredientes en el inventario lo quiero automatico no manual, que yo seleccione churro el programa ya sepa cuáles son los ingredientes de ese producto y así con los demás.
En la programación como establezco está estructura para decirle al programa estos son los ingredientes de x producto y me vaya indicando que tengo en stock si hay un producto que haga falta se vaya realizando la compra

[image: En la imagen 2 se puede observar lo que llevo hasta el momento, esos son los registros de los productos como pan leche huevos, etc y yo los puedo modificar o registrar uno nuevo]

Comment: Buenos Días, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow, Crea una hoja la llamas producto_ingrediente y en dicha hoja tienes tantas filas como ingrediente tiene un producto, colocas una columna ID_Producto la cual te va a determinar cual es el producto que vas a relacionar con los ingredientes y haces un recorrido de dichas filas, por su puesto que cada ingrediente debe tener tambien un id el cual vas a utilizar para descargar el inventario...

Comment: Por cierto te recomiendo que para generar ordenes de compra, en el mismo inventario debes tener un campo que te determine la cantidad minima de ese ingrediente para que cuando lo iguales o estes por debajo generes al momento del cierre del dia dicha orden de compra (te recomiendo que la generes por proveedor), te suguiero que este proceso lo hagas siempre en el cierre, ya sea de caja o como lo llames, asi como otras funciones que tengas como calculos de salario, trabajo al dia, estadisticas, respaldo, etc.

Comment: Excel es una hoja de cálculo, no una base de datos. Te sugiero que contemples la posibilidad de utilizar Access, SQL o similar.

Comment: Esei Gracias por tu comentario y ahí se podria implementar todo lo mismo que tengo plasmado es decir el ingresar las recetas, mi duda esta enfocada en la estructura del programa

Comment: Sí, desde luego. Es laborioso, sin ninguna duda, pero a la larga te compensará más. En Access por ejemplo puedes hacer tus propios formularios, macros y demás. Pero al ser estructura de base de datos es más fácil relacionar información (por ejemplo, ingredientes con un producto). Tomes la decisión que tomes, tendrás que echarle muchas horas de desarrollo.

Comment: super Esei muchas gracias voy a consultar

Answer (score 0):

Bien,

Tienes que hacer 3 bases de datos, una de Productos donde irán en filas los diferentes productos que fabricas, como pueden ser Churros, Donas, Conchas, etc. Y cada uno lleva un ID, Número Identificador Único.
En la tabla 2 va todos los ingredientes que ocupas para hacer todos tus productos con un ID único para cada Fila.
En la Tabla 3 va la Relación Productos-Ingredientes, donde tendrás una columna con el producto y en otra columna los ingredientes y otra columna con las cantidades de cada ingrediente. Aqui no lleva un Id Unico, ya que se repetirá el código del Producto en diferentes filas tantas como ingredientes tenga ese producto.

Con esas 3 tablas podrás hacer Pedido de Materia Prima, etc.

Hay un tema que se llama "Sistema de Gestor de Base de Datos Relacional" donde aprendes a hacer esas 3 tablas...!!!

Saludos.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

La clave es la estructura de las tablas, en este caso necesitas 3.

**Productos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Insumos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Insumos por producto**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es para identificar que insumos lleva cada producto, por lo que si un producto lleva 10 insumos, en la tabla aparecerán los 10 códigos de insumo, uno por fila con una columna de cantidad, por cada fila de insumo debe repetirse el código del producto en cuestión, lo mismo para cada producto.

luego puedes hacer una función con [ciclo for](https://formulasexcel.com/macro-suma-condicional-multiples-hojas-excel/) que recorra esa tabla y devuelva una matriz con los insumos del producto que se requiera, luego con los datos de esa matriz devuelta puedes hacer los cálculos según la cantidad de producto.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim matriz() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    matriz = GetMatriz(2)
    
    Debug.Print "Insumo", "Cantidad"
    For i = 0 To UBound(matriz)
        Debug.Print matriz(i, 0), matriz(i, 1)
    Next i
End Sub

Function GetMatriz(producto As String)
    Dim matrizInsumos() As Variant
    Dim rngInsumosProducto As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim fila As Integer
    Dim nFilas As Integer
    
    Set rngInsumosProducto = Range(Hoja3.Range("B2"), Hoja3.Range("B2").End(xlDown))
    
    nFilas = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngInsumosProducto, producto)
    fila = 0
    ReDim matrizInsumos(nFilas, 1) As Variant
    For Each rng In rngInsumosProducto
        If rng.Text = producto Then
            matrizInsumos(fila, 0) = rng.Offset(0, 1)
            matrizInsumos(fila, 1) = rng.Offset(0, 2)
            fila = fila + 1
        End If
    Next rng
    
    GetMatriz = matrizInsumos
End Function
```

`test` usa la función `GetMatriz` para obtener la matriz de insumos y cantidad del producto que se indica en test, luego se hace el procesamiento, en el ejemplo solo se imprime una tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero tu ya realizarías tus cálculos con los datos de esa tabla para hacer el registro de la salida del almacén, por ejemplo, si la cantidad e producto es 2, entonces se multiplica eso por la cantidad de cada insumo y esa es la salida que se registra en cada caso.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu comentario, lo voy a implementar